# Is there any way to animate window movement in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, animation, transition

I need to move a window to different location, but I dont want to simply make it disappear on its current position and appear on desired position. I use while cycle to move the window one pixel at the time by increasing its y-coordinate, but maybe there is some implemented method for these types of animation in .NET already. Also, I would like to be able to set duration time of the animation. Is there any method in .NET for this kind of animation? This is how I implemented window movement:

```
while (window.Location.Y != newY)
{
    window.Location = new Point(window.Location.X, window.Location.Y + 1);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a rectangle window or you have set `TransparentKey` or other similar methods?

Comment: You need to give the window time to redraw after each time you move it. As it is, it'll do all the moving, one pixel at a time, but so quickly that by the time you see anything, it's in the new position

Comment: you working with System.Windows.Forms (Traditional App Forms) ou System.Windows.Controls (WPF)?

Comment: I use Windows.Forms, window is just classic form with FormBorderStyle set to none, and opacity set to 75%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi andrej you can try this,for WinForms.

```
        IntPtr ID; 
        int counter = 0;//index to move window

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ID = this.Handle; //get handle of form    
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        //place a timer and in his tick event...
        //and choose the interval of the tick.

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right)
                MoveWindow(ID, counter++, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);
            else
                counter = 0;
        }
```

Or without the PInvoke

```
int counter = 0;//index to move window

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    //place a timer and in his tick event...
    //and choose the interval of the tick.

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right)
            this.Location = new Point(counter++, 0);
        else
            counter = 0;
    }
```

This example is just moving the window along X coordinate,you can play around with the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions:
- What is a window you are referring to?
- What type of app is this? WinForms? Web App? something else?

If it is web, do it in the client. Make use of jQuery.